# Driving MOSFETs with Bootstrap connections

Tags: mosfet, power-electronics, mosfet-driver

I'm designing a type of a buck converter which has the following circuitry.

[image]

Simulation runs fine on PLECS and I've added three bootstrap connections to drive these high-side MOSFETs (All top three except `FETD2`). Simulation results to capture voltages across those capacitors is as follows;

[image: Voltages across Bootstrap Capacitors]

I have following questions to clarify before I build this circuit on a PCB.

1. Is the voltage between each gate to source is enough to drive each MOSFET (Probably a Logic type MOSFET)?
2. In simulation, when I use the same 12V source to bootstrap circuit, it throws an error "Cyclic behavior during switching". But when I use a separate source as in the schematic, it works fine. Can't I really use the same source for all bootstrap connections?

   [image: enter code here]
3. Also the PWM frequency needs to be at 1 MHz. Has anyone used a driver circuit which can work at such high frequencies and got good results?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This will fail due to lack of dead time Design and latency from the PWM inverter and times five gain.

Comment: Hello @TonyStewartolderthandirt ! Will I be able to get a considerable amount of dead-time with the operating frequency of 1MHz? Is Bootstrapping the best way in my design?

Comment: No your boostrapping looks wrong and makes no sense.  Normally Low side switch has PWM to drive Diode cap to make bootstrap voltage for high side gate drive.

Comment: Isn't the idea of having a bootstrap connection to always supply a higher voltage at gate terminals with respect to each source terminal? If I don't call this a bootstrap, then would it work?

Comment: Yes wth Vgs > 2.5 Vt but how is in my reply above and no